# How to store and handle textarea with text and multiple pictures in php

Tags: php, image, base64

I've googled around and read alot of post about this, but haven't found any methods that answers my question. I'm quite new here and apologize if this is a stupid question.

I'm creating a logging system in PHP and you can write your log in a text area. I'm using TinyMCE editor which allow to paste screenshots and this is important since users want to show with pictures what they have done.

The problem I'm having is to find a good solution to keep track of where the pictures belong in the post when a post is saved and then should be displayed for another user. The TinyMCE editor convert the screenshots to base64 and this is saved in my DESCRIPTION column in my LOG-table, but I read this is not a good solution because of storage. People advice to store screenshots/images in separate FILE-table.

There is two things I find difficult and need advice on:

**1**. Base64 is saved as a string in my DESCRIPTION-column inbetween the normal text. Is it a solution to use PREG_MATCH to find images here and then store them in separate FILE-table?

**2**. What would be a good way to keep track on the order of the images in the post? I was thinking about making it a  tag in the DESCRIPTION column with reference to ex img1.jpg, img2.jpg in the FILE-table with then another ID-column on the log-post, but I don't know if this can work good or not.

I apologize on beforehand but I've not found any methods on how this is done, even though it is done alot of places, even here!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to store the images' base64 in DB. You should only store their URL or a key that will help you retrieve the URL. Main reasons:

1. The base64 strings bloat the DB and you'll soon get to a size that is hard to maintain
2. When storing images off-DB, you can move them to an external CDN so that your app performance is not affected by processing requests to the static files

TinyMCE allows setting an upload URL that should return the actual URL of the image (instead of base64): https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/

As to your questions:

1. > Base64 is saved as a string in my DESCRIPTION-column inbetween the normal text. Is it a solution to use PREG_MATCH to find images here and then store them in separate FILE-table?

   This would not occur anymore
2. > What would be a good way to keep track on the order of the images in the post?

   You can have a separate table for the images and one connecting table that stores relation between the articles and images and their order.

```
article
+--+-----+
|id|title|
+--+-----+
| 1|Foo  |
+--+-----+

image
+--+----------------------------------+
|id|url                               |
+--+----------------------------------+
| 1|https://www.example.com/image1.png|
| 2|https://www.example.com/image2.png|
+--+----------------------------------+

article_image
+----------+--------+-----+
|id_article|id_image|order|
+----------+--------+-----+
|         1|       1|    1|
|         1|       2|    2|
+----------+--------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I think I understand this now and got a answer with a best practice on how to solve this! I was a bit confused at first with the base64 and how to handle this, but I'll try using the file image upload from TinyMCE.

1 downvote was expected on my question, no surprise haha. Thanks again!